# JSP, show parameter from another table

Tags: sql, jsp

In JSP I have simple foreach, which should display the information from two tables.
First table "Companies" as "country" parameter keeps id of country as a foreign key to another table "Countries".

How can I show country name in this foreach, which keeps in "Companies" as id of country?

```
<c:forEach items="${companies}" var="company">
<c:url var="edit" value="/edit/${company.id}" />
<c:url var="remove" value="/remove/${company.id}" />
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${company.name}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${company.country}" /></td> // In this line
<td><c:out value="${company.address}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${company.phone}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${company.market_cap}" /></td>
<td valign = "top"><a href="${edit}">Edit</a></td>
<td valign = "top"><a href="${remove}">Remove</a></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Companies (id int auto_increment , name varchar(255), country int, address varchar(255), phone varchar(255)primary key(id), foreign key (country) references public.country(id_country));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Country (id_country int auto_increment , name varchar(255), primary key(id_country));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Company` class should have a field of type `Country` instead of having a field containing only the ID of the country.

And the code getting the data out of the database should get the company information with the associated country information.

Something like

```
select company.name, company.address, ... country.id, country.name 
from company 
inner join country on company.country_id = country.id`
```